# Why my app in google play doesn't have button for install on desktop?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

When I open for example this app (it's just random app which I've found) I see that it's possible to install and when I press it I see some random mobile phones.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bol.shop&hl=ru&hl=ru&pli=1

How I can do the same for my app? Should I change some settings in google play or..?

Comment: Those aren't random phones. Those are all the Android devices which have used your Google account. This happens automatically. The selection includes android TVs, watches and Chromecasts.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann But I don't have such devices so that's why strange for me. Anyway, maybe do you know how I can enable this button for my app?

Comment: It can't be enabled separately. Once you have multiple devices, the "Install" or "Install on more devices" button on the Google Play Store website will show a list of all your devices. If your app is available on smart watches and TVs, the play store will show them as well.

Does anyone else use your Google account on their android devices? Friends and family maybe?